# Create 'usable' bins from a vector in R

Tags: r, random

I have a numeric vector with integers which:

1. I want to transform into "bins".
2. I want these bins to be used as sample frames from which I can then sample again, uniformly.

So far I can do both using `findInterval` but I am looking for a way to do it with `cut`.

Let's consider a random vector with integers which will be split in equally sized intervals of length `2`:

```
df = sample(1:100,10)
df
[1] 81 11 38 95 45 14 10 61 96 88
```

Using `findInterval` I get the bins and a approximate way for sampling:

```
breaks = seq(1,max(df+1),by=10)
b <- findInterval(df, breaks)
b
[1]  9  2  4 10  5  2  1  7 10  9
# If b is equal to 1 or 100, then use ifelse() to prevent leaking outside [1,100]
sam <- round(runif(10,ifelse(b==1,10*b-9,10*b-10),ifelse(b==10,10*b,10*b+10))) 
sam
[1] 85 14 39 94 50 16  7 63 93 85
```

Using `cut` I get the intervals:

```
breaks = seq(1,max(df+1),by=10)
cut(df,breaks,right=TRUE)
[1] (71,81] (1,11]  (31,41] <NA>    (41,51] (11,21] (1,11]  (51,61] <NA>    (81,91] Levels: (1,11] (11,21] (21,31] (31,41] (41,51] (51,61] (61,71] (71,81] (81,91]
```

But I don't know how to use those values as intervals from which to sample.

If there is another approach, I would be interested to know!

Comment: What is your `breaks` in `findInterval`?

Comment: Woah, sorry about that! I had placed the two code snippets the other way round originally. `breaks` is the same vector in both cases. I have now made amendments!

Comment: Yeah, I already realised that! Please check my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good Question! I will give you a completely different approach.

So basically you want to perform [Latin Hypercube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_hypercube_sampling) sampling, i.e. stratified uniform sampling in the interval `[0,100]` with each bin of `10`.

For this, it would be easier to download `lhs` package and use `randomLHS` function to perform stratified sampling.

***First step***: Generate uniform draws from every 10 quartiles (strata) as many times as you want. In this example, let's do 5 times:

```
library(lhs)
randomLHS(10, 5)

> X
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
 [1,] 0.92154144 0.22185959 0.49953326 0.66248165 0.79035832
 [2,] 0.47571700 0.05894016 0.55883326 0.34875162 0.98831829
 [3,] 0.57738486 0.64525528 0.04955733 0.50939147 0.46297294
 [4,] 0.17578838 0.83843074 0.27138703 0.87421301 0.16401042
 [5,] 0.03850768 0.40746004 0.69518073 0.23487653 0.55537945
 [6,] 0.83942905 0.52957416 0.84952231 0.14031915 0.84956654
 [7,] 0.22802502 0.79911728 0.76789194 0.09788194 0.08667802
 [8,] 0.61821268 0.93088726 0.30789950 0.95831993 0.36903120
 [9,] 0.70391230 0.11445154 0.97976851 0.42027836 0.61097786
[10,] 0.31385709 0.33557430 0.18389684 0.70124986 0.27601550
```

***Second step***: Although the output of `X` is stratified, the columns are still unsorted. Therefore, when we show the final stratified draws, we sort them.

```
Y <- apply(X,2, function(x) sort(round(x*100)))
> Y
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    4    6    5   10    9
 [2,]   18   11   18   14   16
 [3,]   23   22   27   23   28
 [4,]   31   34   31   35   37
 [5,]   48   41   50   42   46
 [6,]   58   53   56   51   56
 [7,]   62   65   70   66   61
 [8,]   70   80   77   70   79
 [9,]   84   84   85   87   85
[10,]   92   93   98   96   99
```

***NB***: I have done rounding only for convenience to make it obvious but no need to call `round` function if you are happy to have non-integer draws as output).

Comment: If it's a `Good Question!`, then you may upvote. That's actually the point, so good questions stand out.